# convert some of the response values in curl command

Tags: shell, curl, sh

I use the below script to get the average response time for a specific website. It works just fine. I just need to convert some of the values in the response like the **time_total**, i want to view it in milliseconds and the **size_download** in KB format. And in the end of the command where I share the average response time, i also want to print it in milliseconds. Any help is really appreciated.

```
for ((i=1;i<=50;i++)); do curl -w 'Return Code: %{http_code}; Bytes Received: %{size_download}; Response Time: %{time_total}\n' "https://www.google.com" -m 2 -o /dev/null -s; done |tee /dev/tty|awk '{ sum += $NF; n++ } END { If (n > 0); print "Average Response Time =",sum /n;}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pipe the curl output through `awk` and format it as you want like this:

```
curl -w 'Return Code: %{http_code}; Bytes Received: %{size_download}; Response Time: %{time_total}\n' "https://www.google.com" -m 2 -o /dev/null -s | awk  '{printf "Return Code: %d; KiB Received: %f; Response Time(ms): %f\n", $3, $6/1024, $9*1000}'
```

So the oneliner is the following:

```
for ((i=1;i<=50;i++)); do curl -w 'Return Code: %{http_code}; Bytes Received: %{size_download}; Response Time: %{time_total}\n' "https://www.google.com" -m 2 -o /dev/null -s | awk  '{printf "Return Code: %d; KiB Received: %f; Response Time(ms): %f\n", $3, $6/1024, $9*1000}'; done | tee /dev/tty |awk '{ sum += $NF; n++ } END { If (n > 0); print "Average Response Time =",sum /n;}'
```

You can also format the numbers as you want by puttingg, for example %.2f for 2 decimal precision or %d for integer...

Comment: Instead of formatting output in `curl` command, for parsing them by using `$3, $6, $9`, you could reduce `curl` syntax and use `$1, $2/1024, $3*1000`!!

Answer (score 3):

## Three answer here...

As this question is tagged [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) (not bash), here is three different way for doing this, by using `awk` + `bash`, `shell` + `bc` or `bash` alone.

### 1. Using `awk` to process output and compute *averages*

As doing *forks* like `curl ... | awk ...` repetitively, is resource killer, I prefer to run `awk` **only once**, doing the whole formatting output job under `awk`:

```
iter=10
for ((i=iter;i--;));do
     curl -w '%{http_code} %{size_download} %{time_total}\n' \
         "https://www.google.com" -m 2 -o /dev/null -s
     sleep .02
done | awk -v iter=$iter '
    BEGIN {
        ttim=0;tsiz=0;
        printf "  %-3s  %8s %11s %10s\n","Res","Size","Time","Rate"
    };
    {
        printf "  %-3s  %7.2fK %9.2fms %7.2fK/s\n", \
            $1, $2/1024,$3*1000,$2/$3/1024;
        tsiz+=$2;ttim+=$3;
    };
    END {
        printf "Tot    %7.2fK %9.2fms\nAvg    %7.2fK %9.2fms %7.2fK/s\n", \
            tsiz/1024,ttim*1000, tsiz/iter/1024,ttim/iter*1000,tsiz/ttim/1024;
    }'
```

May produce:

```
  Res      Size        Time       Rate
  200    14.61K    128.48ms  113.71K/s
  200    14.75K    131.06ms  112.52K/s
  200    14.73K    131.71ms  111.85K/s
  200    14.72K    130.24ms  113.05K/s
  200    14.66K    134.68ms  108.86K/s
  200    14.69K    131.39ms  111.79K/s
  200    14.63K    131.15ms  111.53K/s
  200    14.70K    126.26ms  116.42K/s
  200    14.71K    129.08ms  113.98K/s
  200    14.68K    131.23ms  111.86K/s
Tot     146.88K   1305.28ms
Avg      14.69K    130.53ms  112.53K/s
```

### 2. Working on *averages* using [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)

As shell don't work with *floating numbers*, you have to use `bc` or another *subprocess* to resolv this operations.

As doing forks like `var=$(echo '3*4'|bc)` is resource killer, I prefer to run `bc` only once, as a *background* process. One advantage of this is `bc` can store *overall* variables (*`total download`* and *`total size`* here).

#### First part: Init some variables and run `bc`

Creating two *fifos* for *backgrounded `bc`* and one *fifo* for `curl`, making parsing of curl's output easier.

Declaring some variables, and `numfmt` function into `bc` for further use...

Note about `numfmt`: This function compute *human readable* presentation from integer value, output two values

- *`octal character`* octal value of `b`, `K`,  `M`, `G`, `P` and `T`  and
- *`floating number`* from submited value, divided by power of 1024

The character from octal could be output by `printf '%b' \\$value` under shell.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

target=${1:-https://www.google.com}
iter=${2:-10}
delay=${3:-.02}

tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
bcin="$tempdir/bcin"  bcout="$tempdir/bcout"  curlout="$tempdir/curlout"
mkfifo       "$bcin"                "$bcout"                  "$curlout"
exec      3<>"$bcin";       exec 4<>"$bcout"
cleanUp() { [ -e "$bcin" ] && rm "$bcin" "$bcout" "$curlout" && rmdir "$tempdir"
            exit;}
trap cleanUp 0 1 2 3 6 15
bc -l <&3 >&4 &
mBc() { echo >&3 "$2"; read -r $1 <&4 ;}
cat >&3 <<EOInitBc
    unit[0]=142;unit[1]=113;unit[2]=115;unit[3]=107;unit[4]=124;unit[5]=120
    define void numfmt (s) {
        if (s==0) { print "0,0\n"; return;};
        p=l(s)/l(1024);
        scale=0;
        p=p/1;
        scale=20;
        print unit[p]," ",s/1024^p,"\n";
    };
    tsiz=0;ttim=0;
EOInitBc
```

#### `#  read variables from curl`

```sh
checkHttpRes() {
    curl -sm2 -w'%{http_code} %{size_download} %{time_total}' -o/dev/null \
         "$1" >"$curlout" &
    read -r cod siz tim <"$curlout"
    mBc rate "tsiz+=$siz;ttim+=$tim;$siz/$tim;"
    mBc mtim "$tim*1000"
    mBc 'hunit hsz' "numfmt($siz)"
    mBc 'hurt hrat' "numfmt($rate)"
    printf '  %-3s  %7.2f%b %9.2fms %7.2f%b/s\n' "$cod" "$hsz" "\\$hunit" \
           "$mtim" "$hrat" "\\$hurt"
}
```

#### `# Last part:` *`main`* `routine`

```sh
printf '  %-3s  %8s %11s %10s\n' Res Size Time Rate
i="$iter"
while [ "$i" -gt 0 ];do
    checkHttpRes "$target"
    sleep "$delay"
    i=$((i-1))
done
mBc 'hutsz htsz' "numfmt(tsiz)"
mBc 'huasz hasz' "numfmt(tsiz/$iter)"
mBc ttim "1000*ttim"
mBc atim "1000*ttim/$iter"
mBc 'huart hart' "numfmt(tsiz/ttim)"
printf 'Tot    %7.2f%b %9.2fms\nAvg    %7.2f%b %9.2fms %7.2f%b/s\n' \
       "$htsz" "\\$hutsz" "$ttim" "$hasz" "\\$huasz" "$atim" "$hart" "\\$huart"
```

#### Run sample:

```
$ ./curlStat.sh http://www.google.com 10 .1
  Res      Size        Time       Rate
  200    14.76K    141.84ms  104.09K/s
  200    14.65K    136.21ms  107.53K/s
  200    14.61K    136.74ms  106.86K/s
  200    14.67K    138.08ms  106.26K/s
  200    14.70K    130.56ms  112.56K/s
  200    14.65K    135.72ms  107.97K/s
  200    14.68K    135.28ms  108.53K/s
  200    14.64K    134.20ms  109.07K/s
  200    14.70K    136.32ms  107.82K/s
  200    14.71K    136.19ms  108.00K/s
Tot     146.77K   1361.14ms
Avg      14.68K    136.11ms  107.83K/s
```

### 3. Last: [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

This question is tagged [sh](/questions/tagged/sh), but `for ((i=...` syntax is a *bashism*. So here is a compact ***pure bash*** version of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
target=${1:-https://www.google.com}  iter=${2:-10} delay=${3:-.02}

txsz(){ local i=$(($1>=1<<50?5:$1>=1<<40?4:$1>=1<<30?3:$1>=1<<20?2:$1>1023?1:0
)) a=(b K M G T P);((i>4?i+=-2:0))&&a=(${a[@]:2})&&set -- $(($1>>20)) $2;local\
r=00$((1000*$1/(1024**i)));printf -v $2 %.2f%s ${r::-3}.${r: -3} ${a[i]};}

declare -i ttim=0 tsiz=0
checkHttpRes() { local code size time ustim hsz hrat
    read -r code size time < <(
      curl -sm2 -w'%{http_code} %{size_download} %{time_total}' -o/dev/null "$1"
    )
    printf -v ustim '%.6f' "$time"
    ustim=$((10#${ustim/.}))
    tsz "$size" hsz
    tsz $(( size*10**7/ustim/10 )) hrat
    ttim+=ustim tsiz+=size ustim=00$ustim
    printf '  %-3s  %8s %9.2fms %8s/s\n' "$code" "$hsz" \
           "${ustim::-3}.${ustim: -3}" "$hrat"
}

printf '  %-3s  %8s %11s %10s\n' Res Size Time Rate
for ((i=iter;i--;)) ;do
    checkHttpRes "$target"
    sleep "$delay"
done

tsz $tsiz htsz
ustim=00$ttim uatim=00$((ttim/iter))
tsz $((tsiz/iter)) hasz
tsz $(( tsiz*10**7/ttim/10  )) hart
printf 'Tot    %8s %9.2fms\nAvg    %8s %9.2fms %8s/s\n' "$htsz" \
       "${ustim::-3}.${ustim: -3}" "$hasz" "${uatim::-3}.${uatim: -3}" "$hart"
```

Without any fork to `bc` nor `awk`, all operation are done in *pseudo float* using *shifted* integers.

This will produce same result:

```
  Res      Size        Time       Rate
  200    14.68K    132.79ms  110.55K/s
  200    14.68K    135.59ms  108.24K/s
  200    14.68K    132.31ms  110.99K/s
  200    14.75K    141.66ms  104.15K/s
  200    14.66K    139.90ms  104.79K/s
  200    14.71K    140.07ms  105.00K/s
  200    14.68K    142.74ms  102.86K/s
  200    14.64K    133.42ms  109.71K/s
  200    14.72K    135.62ms  108.56K/s
  200    14.71K    139.16ms  105.72K/s
Tot     146.92K   1373.25ms
Avg      14.69K    137.32ms  106.98K/s
```

Comment: For strictly this syntax, consider this: `for ((i=10;i--;));do curl -w '%{http_code} %{size_download} %{time_total}\n' "https://www.google.com" -m 2 -o /dev/null -s ;done | awk '{ printf "Return Code: %d; KiB Received: %f; Response Time(ms): %f\n", $1, $2/1024, $3*1000;ttim+=$3;cnt++; };END { printf "Average Response Time = %.4f\n",1000*ttim/cnt;}'` !! This stay a lot lighter! (test by using `time` command, and compare SYS and USR times)